# Ion-Selectable@4.5.0 Version Issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to use ionic-selectable@4.5, into Ionic.

```
   Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3
```

I have installed `npm install ionic-selectable@4.5.0 --save` and imported into bot `app.module` and `feature.module`.

I am getting error like this:

```
[ng] ERROR in node_modules/ionic-selectable/src/app/components/ionic-selectable/ionic-selectable.component.d.ts:1:70 - error TS2724: Module '"../../../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer'. Did you mean 'Renderer2'?
[ng] 1 import { DoCheck, ElementRef, EventEmitter, IterableDiffers, OnInit, Renderer, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
[ng]                                                                        ~~~~~~~~
[ng]   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5929:31
[ng]     5929 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~
[ng]     'Renderer2' is declared here.
```

Need some help.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to fix it was instead of running this command:

```
npm install ionic-selectable@4.5.0 --save // From their npm's page
```

Run this:

```
npm install ionic-selectable --save
```

This will install the latest one, which is around 4.7.x, then the "Rerender" error wont pop out anymore.